# Merge pgAdmin version tags?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, retag-request

We have [pgadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin), [pgadmin-1.18](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-1.18), [pgadmin-3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-3), and [pgadmin-4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-4) tags.

Should the version tags be made synonyms of [pgadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin) and merged?

Related meta Q & A:

- [PgAdmin Tags should be redone](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2712)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268228/166851

Answer (score 3):

Well, [pgadmin-1.18](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-1.18) is definitely useless (it refers to a specific pgAdmin III version).

At the same time, pgAdmin III and pgAdmin 4 are two very different products.  If the question is tagged rightly with [pgadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin), it completely makes sense to indicate which one it is about.  That the users don't use these is not the tags' fault :)

Answer (score 2):

#### The new version tags should be merged.

Parent tag:

- [pgadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin) - 157 questions and 9 followers

Version tags:

- [pgadmin-1.18](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-1.18) - 5 questions and 0 followers
- [pgadmin-3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-3) - 2 questions and 0 followers
- [pgadmin-4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-4) - 6 questions and 0 followers

There is no need for [pgadmin-1.18](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-1.18), [pgadmin-3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-3), or [pgadmin-4](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin-4).

- The single tag [pgadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgadmin) serves to connect subject area experts to questions they may be able to answer.
- Questions can specify the pgAdmin version in the question body if it is important.